# Prepared Statement in ASP.Net C# when using SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am just starting work with ASP.NET C# and my database is SQL Server. I am trying to write a query where I want to use with prepared statement.

This is a query that allowing log in to user:

```
    SqlParameter UserName = new SqlParameter("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30);
    SqlParameter Password = new SqlParameter("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);

    UserName.Value = user.ToLower();
    Password.Value = pass;

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(null, conn);
    command.Parameters.Add(UserName);
    command.Parameters.Add(Password);
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table_users WHERE user_name = '@user' AND password = '@pass';";

    command.Prepare();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    bool tmp = reader.HasRows;
```

`tmp` variable value always `FALSE`, even when I enter exist user with correct password.

If i just remove parameters and write the query this way:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table_users WHERE user_name = '"+user+"' AND password = '"+ pass+"';";
```

`tmp` variable get value `TRUE` for exists users.

I tried to use this syntax for `INSERT INTO` queries and it works correctly.

I already read all the suggestions about changing `@` to `?` and it doesn't work. 
I had an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '?'. Statement(s) could not be prepared.

Help me please,
Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for the **literals** `'@user'` and `'@pass'`, rather than the value from the parameter; use:

```
 command.CommandText =
      "SELECT * FROM table_users WHERE user_name = @user AND password = @pass;";
```

instead. Then look into "salted hashes", and why you should never actually store passwords.

BTW, calling `Prepare()` here isn't helping here. I'm also going to plug dapper-dot-net (free/OSS), which would make this entire thing just:

```
bool authenticated = conn.Query(
    @"select 1 from table_users where user_name = @user and password = @pass",
    new {user = user.ToLower(), pass} ).Any();
```

or, if you want the record:

```
var tableUser = conn.Query<TableUser>(
    @"select * from table_users where user_name = @user and password = @pass",
    new {user = user.ToLower(), pass} ).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now its work. I'll check the "salted hashes".

Comment: @MarkGravell - "BTW, calling Prepare() here isn't helping here." Could you elaborate on _why_ using a prepared statement isn't helping in this usage?

Comment: @Jesse because most databases these days don't care: they have automatic query plan caching on ad-hoc queries that makes any difference basically unmeasurable

Comment: @MarcGravell can i get the query in a string from dapper like "select * from table_users where user_name = user12 and password = 123" with values

Comment: i need the query with parameter's values in string

Comment: @Meer why? What are you trying to do? Parameters *aren't part of any string* - that simply isn't how they are passed via TDS (the underlying protocol).

Comment: I need this only for logging purpose

Comment: I need to write all the database queries in text or other file

Comment: @Meer you might want to look at how mini-profiler does this; it includes tools to capture all queries issued on a connection and to provide a *representation* of what the parameters were (it creates fake `declare` statements in the view, so that you can run the text in SSMS)